# Customizing the appearance of Stripe Payment Element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am currently using the Stripe Payment Element in my React application with the following code:

```
import { useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement, } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

export const PaymentDetails = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe()
  const elements = useElements()

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: 'tabs',
    paymentMethodOrder: ['card']
  }

  return (
    <div className="mb-4">
      <PaymentElement
        id="payment-element"
        options={paymentElementOptions}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to customize the appearance of this payment element align with the theme of my application, specifically changing the colorText for the labels above input fields.

I have reviewed the Stripe documentation, however I wasn't able to amend the appearance of the payment element.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `I have reviewed the Stripe documentation` - what did it suggest? `I wasn't able to amend the appearance` how did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Trying with `colorText` will show `stripe.elements(): "colorText" is not a supported property for ".Label"` in the developer console.

You can see the supported list of CSS properties for each class here : https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api?platform=web#supported-css-properties

Try `-webkit-text-fill-color` and see if that works for you

```
 const appearance = {
  rules: {
    '.Label': {
      '-webkit-text-fill-color': '#FFC0CB',
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you are missing is the Elements provider component. That component takes a prop called `options` where you can pass in an Appearance API config:

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
import { 
  PaymentElement,
  Elements,
} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

export const PaymentDetails = () => {
  const stripePromise = loadStripe('YOUR_PK');

  const elementsOptions = {
    mode: 'payment',
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'usd',
    appearance: {
      theme: 'night',
      variables: {
        colorText: '#ffffff',
      },
    },
  };

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: 'tabs',
    paymentMethodOrder: ['card']
  };

  return (
    <div className="mb-4">
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={elementsOptions}>
        <PaymentElement
          id="payment-element"
          options={paymentElementOptions}
        />
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is mostly a copy/paste example from this [Stripe docs page](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=payment#add-and-configure-the-elements-provider-to-your-checkout-page).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Appearance API](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api) to customize the Payment Element to match your own design scheme.

Comment: how? that link goes to the generic appearance docs, not react stripe js specific, which works differently. Please add an example.